# First 16 bytes of AES decryption are garbage

Tags: c#, aes

I'm trying to replicate this Javascript in C#

```
iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(bkZ)
key = CryptoJS.SHA256(skH)

function ovelDecrypt(data)
{
    var ret = null;
    try
    {
        var contentCiphertext = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create(
        {
            ciphertext : CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(data)
        });
        var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(contentCiphertext, key,
        {
            mode : CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            iv : iv,
            padding : CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });
        ret = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    }
    catch(ShowMsg)
    {
        alert(ShowMsg")
    }
    return ret;
};
```

but using the code below the first 16 bytes of the decrypted string are garbage (but always the same for the same input)

```
private static string bkZ = "a5e8d2e9c1721ae0e84ad660c472c1f3";
private static string skH = "nnsdfb23nmasdl047sm"; //For testing only
private static string ovelDecrypt(string cipherText)
{
    //Generate the initialization vector
    int[] iv = new int[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        iv[i] = (~Convert.ToInt32(bkZ.Substring(i * 8, 8), 16) + 1) * -1;

    //Generate the key
    byte[] key;
    using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
        key = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(skH));

    using (RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        int CHUNK_SIZE = 128;
        rijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        rijndael.KeySize = CHUNK_SIZE;
        rijndael.BlockSize = CHUNK_SIZE;
        rijndael.Key = key;
        rijndael.IV = iv.SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes).ToArray();
        ICryptoTransform transform = rijndael.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] cipherbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        byte[] decryptedOutput = transform.TransformFinalBlock(cipherbytes, 0, cipherbytes.Length);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedOutput);
    }
}
```

My cipher text is

```
iCY+Oars3gD/TDBMDoUyPxbRAglekyv7MdNW9I/lV1uUu88F3KISPhQi0NHwVO6DzFEGsf8MPxCZpTTWSCeaytYWb/K/f7cGyb7BlhgmRzksApDdMDC62kwh5ato5VShfOUd2VeD0YENCRQ79HpVSDd5ibtuNd2UqANsGw85leEo4kVKzL06RmRe6VY43iqV+/bxNt1BPzaaENKkcIat7fYeid5vBFcWsVU8oM0vr0lgTlGXZqstSWQcuMmLXQy5becJtQ+Bkj5obPpW+kC0FHLJJsoS/ZAd/aaSWfRzzo9nfEE1YPgPRa1C3qufHiBBn6jU2YC2cN591nlas5QurJQ3PBgBR/rEcoqk61/R+Qr8bBaMNT1C3j9aYIrVmg3q74RKOJWRkCMije1+EtwHMf/O49TMiQOu7I9VIJmheXc=
```

```
Javascript output: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9xsACLpNPipRFBrSZ8FOXSTa4YkrI2p3vxpBPTV2tzBZ6tYUCtLk-0lOcFg9y5f_thL8wlqMnQ=m37?&jparams=ODcuMjU0LjczLjE3Nw&upx=TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFdpbmRvd3MgTlQgMTAuMDsgV2luNjQ7IHg2NCkgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM3LjM2IChLSFRNTCwgbGlrZSBHZWNrbykgQ2hyb21lLzc3LjAuMzg2NS45MCBTYWZhcmkvNTM3LjM2#betaHost"
C# output:         "$NN<RRG???P??Pleusercontent.com/9xsACLpNPipRFBrSZ8FOXSTa4YkrI2p3vxpBPTV2tzBZ6tYUCtLk-0lOcFg9y5f_thL8wlqMnQ=m37?&jparams=ODcuMjU0LjczLjE3Nw&upx=TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFdpbmRvd3MgTlQgMTAuMDsgV2luNjQ7IHg2NCkgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM3LjM2IChLSFRNTCwgbGlrZSBHZWNrbykgQ2hyb21lLzc3LjAuMzg2NS45MCBTYWZhcmkvNTM3LjM2#betaHost"
```

When debugging I've checked that the IV, key, cipher text, mode and padding match but i still getting garbage. Based off other posts on SO i think this is an IV problem but i couldn't figure this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try decode IV as byte array. you need handle byte order correctly for integer.